# In NumPy, how do I set array b's data to reference the data of array a?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Say I have ndarray a and b of compatible type and shape. I now wish for the data of b to be referring to the data of a. That is, without changing the array b object itself or creating a new one. (Imagine that b is actually an object of a class derived from ndarray and I wish to set its data reference after construction.) In the following example, how do I perform the b.set_data_reference?

```python
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.empty_like(a)
b.set_data_reference(a)
```

This would result in b[0] == 1, and setting operations in one array would affect the other array. E.g. if we set a[1] = 22 then we can inspect that b[1] == 22.

N.B.: In case I controlled the creation of array b, I am aware that I could have created it like

```
b = np.array(a, copy=True)
```

This is, however, not the case.

Comment: could you provide a small sample of the a and b array to save people having to create their own examples which may not be appropriate to your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy does not support this operation. If you controlled the creation of `b`, you might be able to create it in such a way that it uses `a`'s data buffer, but after `b` is created, you can't swap its buffer out for `a`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Every variable in python is a pointer so you can use directly `=` as follow

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = a
```

You can check that `b` refers to `a` as follow

```
assert a[1] == b[1]
a[1] = 4
assert a[1] == b[1]
```

Comment: You are letting the identifier point to the object underlying a. That is not the same as having the data of b refer to the data of a. Imagine b is a given object of another class, which inherits from ndarray.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when functions are not always supposed to create their own buffer they implement an interface like

```
def func(a, b, c, out=None):
    if out is None:
        out = numpy.array(x, y)
    # ...
    return out
```

that way the caller can control if an existing buffer is used or not.